# Does it have a pole of order $km$ at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f,g$ be meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$. If $f$ has a zero of order $k$ at $z=a$ and $g$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z=0$, then will the order of pole at $z=a$ is $g(f(z))$?
>
> $f(z)=(z-a)^kf_1(z)$ and $g(z)=\frac{g_1(z)}{z^m}$ thus $g(f(z))=\frac{g_1((z-a)^kf_1(z))}{(z-a)^{km}(f_1(z))^m}$ , thus I think pole at $z=a$ will be of $km$.

Comment: this sounds correct.

Comment: ...and your own argument proves it.